# Consider redirecting to https by default?

Tags: feature-request, ssl

Not really a question, but more of a nudge to consider having https everywhere on the site.

I know much has been [said](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) on the difficulty of implementing https everywhere on the StackExchange network, but it has been quite a while and since then there has been some development in the world of ssl cert generation (letsencrypt, etc), so maybe more can be done about it?

Its not really a "need" per-se, since people can just bookmark the site, but I believe most visits to SE come from search engine where the links are in http, and it would help prevent modification to the content of the page by 3rd parties (Example is an ads injected by an ISP in Indonesia).

Edit:
I'm aware there has been several discussion on the topic, but I would like to re-open the discussion on the topic since there has been some changes on the available options for implementing SSL. And I also would like to point out another reason to have https other than to prevent eavesdropping (e.g. ads injection).

[image: injected ads]

Comment: I agree with you - HTTPS is needed. For now though, you can (should !) use an extension like [HTTPS everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere%20).